# Sharepoint 2019 news alerts with Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, 2019

Sharepoint 2019 on-premises and local data gateway to connect with Power Automate.
I'd like to send mail alerts when a news post is published.
How can I distinguish between news posts and normal pages?
There is no 'Promoted state' field in Site Pages list.

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

To send mail alerts when a news post is published, you can create a Microsoft Flow that triggers when a new item is added to the Site Pages list. You can then use a Condition action to check if the item is a news post or a normal page. Unfortunately, there is no ‘Promoted state’ field in Site Pages list to distinguish between news posts and normal pages. However, you can use the Content Type field to differentiate between the two.

**Here are the steps to create the Flow:**

1. Open Power Automate and create a new flow.
2. Select the **When an item is created** trigger and select the Site Pages list.
3. Add a Condition action and set the condition to check if the **Content Type** field equals the news post content type.
4. If the condition is true, add a Send an email action to send the mail alert.

Please note that you will need to have the On-Premises Data Gateway installed to connect to your SharePoint 2019 on-premises environment. You can find more information on how to set up and configure the gateway in the [Microsoft Learn documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/gateway-reference)